# Vaadin exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.view.ForecastInputs$2 cannot be cast to com.example.view.ForecastInputs

Tags: java, vaadin7

I'm getting the following exception in Vaadin:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.view.ForecastInputs$2 cannot be cast to com.example.view.ForecastInputs

At this line:

```
ForecastInputs forecastInputs = (ForecastInputs) UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("forecastInputs");
```

I think this is because I'm storing and retrieving the object from Vaadin session multiple times.

Please help me with this.

Comment: What type was set? `UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("forecastInputs", ???);`

Answer (score 0):

Like Ben said, you get what you put.

It seems you add an object of an anonymous inner class of your `ForecastInputs`. I assume, you did inside your class ForecastInputs something like this

```
Button x = new Button();
x.addClickListener((e) -> { UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("forecastInputs", this); });
```

But you should add attribute `ForecastInputs.this`